# SQL Update Efficiency and Blocking Concern

Tags: sql-server

Say I have some SQL similar to the below, which is an update with many joins. The number of rows actually being updated may be 1000's or potentially only a few. The actual join takes a long time as there are millions of rows involved, probably around 30s. Would the below only lock the trade table t on the rows that need to be updated or is it being locked as the joins are underway? So would it be better to use a CTE or temp table to gather this data and then update?

I'm having deadlock issues and wanted to make sure updates like this aren't part of the problem.

```
update
t
set
t.price = d.latestprice * f.rate
from
trade (nolock) t
inner join tradedetails (nolock) d on d.ID = t.ID
...
...
inner join fxdetails (nolock) f on f.CCY = t.CCY
```

Comment: The `(nolock)` hints are an attempt to avoid deadlocks?

Comment: How much time does the (corresponding) Select take? (`SELECT t.price, d.latestprice, f.rate FROM ...`) Have you checked the execution plan to find out why it is taking so much time to update only 1000 rows?

Comment: Can you give some more information about the tables involved in the `JOIN`? Or post an execution plan of the `SELECT` to see why it's slow.

Comment: @Tony SQL-Server has execution plans for `UPDATE` as well.

Comment: I guess my question is, say only 2 rows would be updated and I just updated these with 1 join across a temp table that has the latestprice and rate I need. In terms of locking the table t, is there any difference between this or using the above SQL which after all the joins will update the same 2 rows? So will the table t, just be locked on the 2 rows with the ID's I want to amend in both cases? Or is there a difference between the 2 approaches?

Comment: What is the table `t` you are updating? Saying "...a temp table that has the latest price and rate I need." is a little worrying, why are you storing data in a temp table and not in the main tables of your DB? Updating from a temp table could result in inconsistencies in your data if the tables in the larger `JOIN` query are changed before your write.

Comment: The temp table would be populated from the query I provided, and then immediately used for the update and then discarded. So effectively going from a straight update with multiple joins to grabbing this data into a temp table and then updating. The question is whether there is any difference in potential locking of the table t from either of these 2 approaches. As many processes may want to access t and I don't want any unnecessary locking, just the rows that need to be updated.

Comment: With the update you are trying to do, does it matter if any of the data involved in the large `JOIN` changes before you write the update? If the update is independent of the other data then using a temp table should not be a problem. But is there a situation where the data might change before your write and therefore invalidate the update? I'm guessing probably not as, from the table names, you seem to be recording stock market trades (historical information)

Comment: Yes the update is independent is independent of the other data, so I guess this is the way to go then. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Table locking is a *good* thing, it's done so your data doesn't get corrupted.

I wouldn't recommend using NOLOCK when writing data, you should have a look at the answers to [Is the NOLOCK (Sql Server hint) bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452996/is-the-nolock-sql-server-hint-bad-practice)

An article linked from the question ([SQL Server NOLOCK Hint & other poor ideas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/davidlean/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas)) has as it's first recommendation:

> Do not use any HINTs until your testing proves that you have an issue
> that can’t be solved any other way than by using a HINT.

As ypercube commented, I would work out why your `SELECT` query is slow before applying lock hints to you query.

Answer (score 1):

I have always found it is more efficient when you get the exact data that you want to update and store it in a temporary table. This will make the Update statement as simple as possible and will most definitely speed things up a bit.

Hope this helps

B

Comment: Also try and find if there are any ways you can restrict the data before you join i.e. conditions in the WHERE clause. The earlier restriction takes place the less chance it will slow things down later in the query.

Comment: What happens if the data in the base table changes between the time you populate the temp table and the time the update statement runs?  I'd be hesitant to recommend using a temp table without knowing that it wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @StrayCatDBA your concern is valid, but the same problem can occur with all other isolation levels except for serializable and snapshot.

Answer (score -1):

SQL Server will U-lock any row that it needs from the table or view or CTE referenced in the `FROM` clause. If it needs to scan the table, it U-locks it. If it needs to read 3 rows, it only U-locks them.

This is usually a good thing but you might try the following workaround:

```
UPDATE t1 SET ...
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
JOIN ...
```

Introduce a redundant join. Do all the filtering on t2 which is not locked. When the set of rows to be updated is determined SQL Server will probably seek into t1 and only lock exactly the rows that need to be updated.

The full discussion of this pattern and associated locking is too long for this answer. It is worth playing around with it.

Actually, you can also use a temp table to store the update information. That has more overhead though and not needed here.